# timelineMax stagger start next after finished

Tags: gsap

hello I am trying to use staggerTo from timelineMax
my code is

```
this.tl.staggerTo(this.chartProxies,1,{
        repeat:1,
        yoyo:true,
        deviation:5,
    },3)
```

chartProxies is my array and it has a deviation property 
array length is 5
what I want to do is: change deviation of an element in array and then starts next when yoyo of previous one finished

as I understand it, duration of each element is 1 and since yoyo is true it will cost 2 second for each to start and finish 
when I write 3 second delay at the end, timeline waits 3 seconds after yoyo is finished but if I change it to 1 second the next one starts before the current is finished
what am I supposed to do
thanks

Answer (score 0):

A stagger value of `3` like you have is **not** a delay of 3 seconds. It is shorthand for `stagger: { each: 3 }`, which means that it will start each animation 3 seconds after the previous one *starts*.

You're right in that it will take 2 seconds for each to finish because of your duration of 1 and repeat of 1, so that means there will be 1 second of nothing before the next animation starts.

But when you change the `3` to `1` It starts before the other one ends because that's what it does.

If you want it to act as a delay instead of the behavior it has, you could calculate it yourself by using something like this:

```
const dur = 1;
const delay = 1;
this.tl.staggerTo(this.chartProxies, dur, {
  repeat:1,
  yoyo:true,
  deviation:5,
}, dur * 2 + delay)
```

P.S. You'd get help even more quickly over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/). We'd love to have you around!

P.P.S. I recommend using [GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3). There are lots of improvements!

Comment: u write that "there will be 1 second of nothing before the next animation starts" but 3 waits 3 seconds not 1. 
if I type stagger value more than duration value it waits stagger time after finished

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding. A stagger value of 3 is from the START of the previous animation, not the end, as I said in this answer. And since you have a `repeat` of `1` and the `duration` is `1`, then in the timeline it will play the animation for the first second, go backwards for the second second, wait a second, then start the next animation. If you provided a minimal example of your code/issue it'd help a lot with your understanding I think.